# Auto-hiding Gnome panel should be always on top -- Which gconf key to use?

Tags: gnome, gnome-panel, gconf

I've set my panels to auto-hide and want them to be on top of everything once they scroll out.

Which gconf-key do I have to use to achieve this?

Also I looked for a list of gconf keys -- somebody knows?

Cheers,
T

Answer (score 1):

What you're seeing is a [bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-panel/+bug/511980). It occurs on my system (11.04) from time to time but I can't properly reproduce it and don't have a reliable fix either. It's not a simple *gconf* setting. There are various workarounds on the [ubuntu forums](http://ubuntuforums.org/archive/index.php/t-1313657.html) you can try.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for:

```
ALT-F2 > "gconf-editor" > apps > panel > toplevels > top_panel_screen0 > auto_hide_size > 1
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but NOPE!

The panel scrolls out, but it does so BEHIND the windows. Wanted is IN FRONT of the windows.

Thx,
T

Comment: ... nobody got an idea?

Comment: Can you add a screenshot of the problem ?